# How can statistics be used to avoid "Lending False Credibility To Decisions We've Already Made"

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, bias, validity, ethics

In light of this article [Data Science Has Become About Lending False Credibility To Decisions We've Already Made](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kalevleetaru/2019/03/24/data-science-has-become-about-lending-false-credibility-to-decisions-weve-already-made/#6a7f76651d87) published in Forbes, I would appreciate input from the statistical and data science community:

**1. What can be done to ensure credibility in findings based on machine learning and big data?**

**2. Is hypothesis testing inherently superior and more credible than machine learning?**

The article begins with:

> One of the greatest failures of data science (...) [i]t no longer matters
> what our data actually says or whether the data we are using is in any
> way relevant to the questions we ask of it. All that matters is that
> we can justify our preordained decisions with the certainly of “data.”
>
> As we rapidly undermine the promise of data science, will our trust in
> data fade with it?
>
> [O]ur era of searching data for answers has
> devolved into searching data until we find support for the answer
> we've already decided upon.

It concludes saying:

> Putting this all together, data science is no longer about analyzing
> data or giving our data the opportunity to speak to us.
>
> Most dangerously, it has become about the misuse of statistics, data,
> research methodologies and the scientific method to lend false
> credibility to decisions that have already been made.
>
> We no longer devise a hypothesis and test it using data. We start with
> the conclusion we want and find the data and methods to support it.

Comment: So, the author of that article is painting so may people with such a wide brush that It's liable to collapse under its own gravitational weight.  That said, if you dialed back the rhetoric, there's a point there about both hype, and an abandonment of the scientific method in some business communities.

Comment: There’s not a single specific example of anything in this article.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this article does not provide any example to support its claims. But the claims made are very troubling. That is why I would appreciate input from the statistical community: `1. What can be done to ensure credibility in findings based on machine learning and big data? 2. Is hypothesis testing inherently superior and more credible than machine learning?`

Comment: @TheLaconic The article mentions specifically the report "A Decadal Survey of the Social and Behavioral Sciences: A Research Agenda for Advancing Intelligence Analysis" , with Twitter being used by some researchers as a data source, while (according to the author) this is a terrible source for the quantitative research they conducted back then.

Comment: This is not something new (e.g. the history of the tobacco industry), but I find this is a good question. What kind of methods or strategies have been proven useful to resist the pressure to "give already known results"?

Comment: The two big questions posed here are so different that they shouldn't be addressed in a single thread.  Both look like they are likely to attract differing opinions and so neither is suitable here on CV.